# How to validate with regex the format of an itinerary field in bigquery to extract the departure and arrival?

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

Good morning,

I was working on a regex to validate and extract some iata codes from an itinerary to create a departure and arrival column

I have for example this input:

```
123424-LYS-OPO-PAR
LYS-OPO
OPO-PAR
OPO-PAR-LYS
LYS-OPO-PAR-...-BKK
12312312-312-231-231
```

To get this:

| departure | arrival |
| --- | --- |
| LYS | PAR |
| LYS | OPO |
| OPO | PAR |
| OPO | LYS |
| LYS | BKK |
| Nothing | Nothing |

To get this in BQ. I was trying:

```
select
    case
        when regexp_contains(iata.itinerary, r'^\W-|[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]{3}')
            then split(regexp_substr(iata.itinerary), r'^\W|[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]{3}'), '-')[offset(0)] 
        else 'Nothing'
    end as departure,
    case
        when regexp_contains(iata.itinerary, r'^\W-|[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]{3}')
            then ARRAY_REVERSE(split(regexp_substr(upper(iata.itinerary), r'^\W|[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]{3}'), '-'))[safe_offset(0)]
        else 'Nothing'
    end as arrival 
from iata_data iata
```

But I dont know how to deal with more than X number of iata codes in BQ

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if there is one iata code in an itinerary ?  do you want *departure* and *arrival* to be same ?

Comment: Thanks @Jaytiger! Yes that would be as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider below.

```sql
WITH iata_data AS (
  SELECT '123424-LYS-OPO-PAR' itinerary UNION ALL
  SELECT 'LYS-OPO' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'OPO-PAR' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'OPO-PAR-LYS' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'LYS-OPO-PAR-...-BKK' UNION ALL
  SELECT '12312312-312-231-231'
)
SELECT COALESCE(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(iata.itinerary, '[A-Z]{3}')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)], 'Nothing') departure,
       COALESCE(ARRAY_REVERSE(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(iata.itinerary, '[A-Z]{3}'))[SAFE_OFFSET(0)], 'Nothing') arrival
  FROM iata_data iata;
```

or,

```
SELECT COALESCE(codes[SAFE_OFFSET(0)], 'Nothing') departure,
       COALESCE(codes[SAFE_OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(codes) - 1)], 'Nothing') arrival
  FROM iata_data iata, UNNEST([STRUCT(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(iata.itinerary, '[A-Z]{3}') AS codes)]);
```

**Query results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
select itinerary, 
  ifnull(regexp_extract(itinerary, r'[A-Z]{3}', 1, 1), 'Nothing') as departure,
  ifnull(reverse(regexp_extract(reverse(itinerary), r'[A-Z]{3}', 1, 1)), 'Nothing') as arrival,
from iata_data
```

with output

[image]